# modern website multi platform screenshots

Tags: user-interface, photoshop, fireworks

Is there any software or psd template to make multi platform (iphone, ipad, browser...) website screenshots like these:

http://vendhq.com/images/splash_image.jpg

http://vendhq.com/images/tour/pos_ipad.jpg

I'm looking for something that gives you all the shadow effects, iphone/ipad frames, etc OOTB, and not just a traditional screen capture app like Snagit

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use this. http://ami.responsivedesign.is/ I use Firebug to change the background color to what I need.

Answer (score 1):

You should try PlaceIt for adding your designs in more "real life" environments.
Just choose a scene and drop your design on it.

http://placeit.breezi.com

This kind of wizardry always makes clients happy!

Answer (score 0):

You could use Browsershots:

http://browsershots.org/

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I'm looking for. I know that page is good for cross-browser testing, but they're just raw screen captures. I'm looking for some photoshop template or app that gives you all the cool effects (shadows, ipad, iphone frames, etc)